# type casting extract property generic type from object

Tags: typescript

not sure if this is possible in typescript:

I have a class:

```
class Foo<T> {
...
}
```

then I need to have method that converts type:

```
{
 a: Foo<number>,
 b: Foo<string>
}
```

to:

```
{
 a: number,
 b: string
}
```

so I could use it as:

```
const ret = test({ a: new Foo<number>(), b: new Foo<string>() })
ret.a = 10; // number
ret.b = "test"; // string
```

Thank you!

---- just to give more details, in fact `Foo` looks like this:

```
class Foo<T> {
 constructor(public key: string) {
 }
}
```

in method test I need to have mapping between passed object properties `a`, `b` and `Foo.key`.

so test call looks like:

```
test({ a: new Foo<number>("aaa"), b: new Foo<string>("bbb") });
```

inside test I need to know this info: `{ a: "aaa", b: "bbb" }`, outside: `{ a: number, b: string }`

Hope it's more clear now:)

Comment: It depends on how `Foo` is implemented but are you sure you need this?

Comment: in fact Foo constructor takes `string` as input, and inside `test` method I need to map properties of passed object `a`, `b` with passed string, but outside I need to have object with `a`, `b` and it's types

Comment: Unless you have mapping code somewhere else, your implementation is impossible currently due to type erasure. In other words, `new Foo<number>("aaa")` is just `new Foo("aaa")` at runtime.

Comment: Anyway, you can write a type like `type UnFoo<T> = { [P in keyof T]: T[P] extends Foo<infer U> ? U : T[P] };`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure this answers what you're actually looking for but it appears to answer the question as written:

```js
class Foo<T> {
    constructor(public value: T) {
    }
}

interface IX {
    a: Foo<number>;
    b: Foo<string>;
}

const test = (x: IX) => ({
    a: x.a.value,
    b: x.b.value,
});

const ret = test({ a: new Foo<number>(3), b: new Foo<string>("3") })
ret.a = 10;
ret.b = "test";
```

It depends entirely on how you're wrapping the value you want to extract from the class `Foo`

Comment: For me it won't work, please see more details I added in original post. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
foo<Z extends object>(map: Z): { [K in keyof Z]: Z[K] extends Foo<infer P> ? P : Z[K] }> {
...
}
```

did the trick - thank you @Aluan Haddad